# Calculate percentage change from baseline in a time series dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a time series data frame in absolute values, but I wanted to plot them as a percentage change from a baseline year (the first year). The columns in the data frame are the mean, and the higher and lower bounds to plot variation.

Below is the solution I came up with. It works just fine, but is there more simple/repeatable way of doing the same thing?

```
# ---- dummy data
year <- c(1991:2023)
mean <- rnorm(33, 200000, 200)
low <- mean-200
high <- mean+200
df <- data.frame(year,mean,low,high)


# ---- the solution
percentchange <- function(x,y){
  (y-x)/x
}

baseline <- data.frame(mean=rep(df$mean[1], 33), low=rep(df$mean[1], 33), high=rep(df$mean[1], 33))

df_change <- percentchange(baseline[c(1:3)], df[c(2:4)])
df_change$year <- df$year


# ---- the plot
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df_change, aes(year, mean)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=low, ymax=high), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw()
```

I'm quite new to R so if you have a better solution, an explanation would be wonderful.

Comment: Great use of R's vectorization features. If it gives the right results, I would use it.